# How interpret the notation $f:\{0,\dots, N-1\} \rightarrow \{0,\dots, N-1\}$, $N$ is a number of the form $2^n$?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, automata, discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra

I need help how to interpret the following notation for $f$:

> Zeroes and ones form a binary number which can be converted to
>   decimal notation. Thus, we may think of the computer as calculating a function
>   $$
> f:\{0,\dots, N-1\} \rightarrow \{0,\dots, N-1\}, 
> $$
>   where $N$ is a number of the form $2^n$, and $n$ is the number of bits in the computer memory. In this description, $f$ must be a function because the computer cannot generate two or more different outputs from the same input. We assume without loss of generality that the domain and codomain of $f$ are of the same size. In other words, we assume that both the input and the output of the computer have the same number of bits.

***Update:***

*I understand the function notation 
\begin{align}
f&:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R_+ \\
x& \mapsto f(x)
\end{align}
so if $x\in \mathbb R$ we have $f(x)\in\mathbb R_+$.
So far so good.*

*However I don't follow the meaning (mapping) of $\{0, \dots, N-1\}$ in this case.*

**Attempt 1:**

Say I have the decimal number $5$, so $N= 5$. I guess "of the form $2^n$" means a binary number, i.e. $5_{10}=(0101)_2$ and thus $n=4$. So I have the function
$$
f: \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4\} \rightarrow \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4\}
$$

Is this correct?

**Attempt 2:**

Is the domain and codomain of $f$ a binary number?  I.e. **no commas in the sets**
$$
f: \{0101\} \rightarrow \{0101\}
$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3624705/14578, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/124092/755.    Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was cross-posted.

Answer (score 0):

A function $f\colon \{0,\ldots,N-1\} \to \{0,\ldots,N-1\}$ accepts an input from $\{0,\ldots,N-1\}$ and outputs something from $\{0,\ldots,N-1\}$. Just like any function $f\colon A \to B$.

In this case, we are interested in $N$ of the form $2^n$. That is, we are interested in values of $N$ such that $N = 2^n$. For example, $N = 256$. We *identify* the set $\{0,\ldots,N-1\}$ with the set of binary strings of length $n$, using binary notation. For example, if $N = 8$, then the interpretation works as follows:

- 0 is interpreted as 000.
- 1 is interpreted as 001.
- 2 is interpreted as 010.
- 3 is interpreted as 011.
- 4 is interpreted as 100.
- 5 is interpreted as 101.
- 6 is interpreted as 110.
- 7 is interpreted as 111.

As an example, the complementation function $f\colon \{0,\ldots,7\} \to \{0,\ldots,7\}$ is given by $f(x) = 7-x$. You can check that it corresponds to complementing the binary representation of the input.